# Is there any Issue or Risk of data lose if i am sending URL encoded data with a UTF8 encoding inside WebClient()

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on an asp.net mvc-4 web application . and my asp.net mvc-4 web application integrates with a 3rd party API. now the third part API should accept the json object in url encoded format + the 3rd party API allow passing non-ASCII characters.

so to be able to send url encoded json data and pass non-ASCII characters. i ended up with the following `WebClient`:-

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())                
              {
 var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mainresourceinfo);      
 string url = currentURL + "resources?AUTHTOKEN=" + pmtoken;
 Uri uri = new Uri(url);
 wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
 wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 crudoutput = wc.UploadString(uri, "INPUT_DATA=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(data));
               }
```

where as shown above i have defined :-

```
wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

to allow passing non-ASCII characters.

also since the 3rd part API should accept the json in url encoded format so i ended up defining `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(data)` inside the `UploadString` and defining `wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`

First Question. is defining all these encoding and url encoding together a valid appraoch ?

Second Question. i though that defining

```
wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

will ONLY affect how the data will be uploaded,, mainly to allow non-ASCII characters,, but seems `wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;` will also affect how the `UploadString` call output will be handled...so in my case if i i remove the `wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;` and the API rely back `"The resource named ££123 has been added successfully"` ,, then the `crudoutput` variable will have a value such as `"The resource named ÂÂ123 has been added successfully"`.where the ££ will be assigned as ÂÂ . so this mean the  `wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;` will mainly affect how the data will be uploaded and also how the output will be handled ? is this correct ?

So can anyone adivce about my above 2 questions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You approach is valid as long as your `pmtoken` doesn't contain any characters such as `&` or `+` which have special meaning in a url.  If it does, I'd recommend using URLEncode() to encode the `pmtoken`.  As for your second question, yes it affects both request and response.  Also make sure you `data` is not extremely long. Cos, browser(s) may have a limit on the url length and may cause issue.  AFAIK, Microsoft has 2K character limit on url.

Comment: but why i need to worry about the URL length i am using UploadString() so the data will be uploaded and will not be part of the URL is this correct ?

Comment: My bad, you're correct. Didn't notice the UploadString, just saw the concatenation (+) and assumed you're appending it to the url.

Comment: so returning back to my original question is there any risk of data lose or conflict data if i send url encoded data over UTF8 encoding ?

Comment: If you have control over the server side code then no risk of data loss.  But if you're posting/sending data to a external url/service and if that service reads it as a ASCII string instead of unicode then there could be some data loss.  In this day and age, I seldom see services that read input strings as ASCII, so not much to worry there.

Comment: now i already did some tests by sending data containing non-ASCII characters such as £¬123 to the external API,, and they were added corrected , also the API replied back with a correct message such as "Resource named £¬123 has been added" .. so this mean that the external API i am working with accept unicode is this correct ,, and there is not any problem of data lose?

Comment: yep, you're good to go. Nothing to worry about data loss then.

Comment: final note .. can you send me any link or article that talks about if encoding a request will also affect how decoding the response will work ? because i have read some articles which mentioned that encoding the request will not have any effect on the response ... not sure about this point

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx
Gets and sets the Encoding used to **upload and download** strings.

Comment: i think the link you provide mainly talk about UploadString and DownloadString it does not say any thing about how the API reply will be populated inside my  crudoutput  variable ?

Comment: the variable is a string type. string would handle unicode(UTF-8) without any problems. So if you're seeing odd characters, it is because the DownloadString or UploadString method is not encoding the http response properly before putting it into the string (crudoutput).

Comment: so this mean defining " wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;" will affect these 2 things ; 1) how the string inside the UploadString() will be encoded and then uploaded .2)and also how the http response will be encoded ?? is this correct?